# Returning Multiple Values from Oracle Function

Tags: arrays, oracle11g

I want to return multiple values FROM ORACLE FUNCTION to fill the drop-down list box in front end and values are database constants of package.

I have tried this function:

```
return varchar2
IS

BEGIN

return  pr_package.constant1_string;

return pr_package.constant2_string;

  end;
```

I need a help as soon as possible, suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple returns from a function.

You could return a collection from a function.  Something like

```
CREATE TYPE string_array
    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_string_array
   RETURN string_array
IS
  l_string_array string_array := new string_array( pr_package.constant1_string, 
                                                   pr_package.constant2_string );
BEGIN
  RETURN l_string_array;
END;
```

Or you can create a pipelined table function.  Using the same type, you can then pipe multiple rows

```
  1  create or replace function pipeline_test
  2   return string_array
  3   pipelined
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    pipe row( 'Foo' );
  7    pipe row( 'Bar' );
  8    return;
  9* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table( pipeline_test );

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Foo
Bar
```